# React "cannot read property 'pathname'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was making some updates in a create-react-app, but just on one component. I came back to my work and got this error message. I double checked my package.json, but nothing seems to be changed.
[image]

Comment: Please post text, not  images.

Comment: Probably need to check whatever it was you were changing; do a diff against the previously-committed version--did you modify any `<Link>` tags or the properties you're passing to it?

Comment: seems to be an issue in your routes configuration. Could you provide your routes code?